# Importing files in a specific order using glob

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob

I have a long timeserie where each year is archived within a folder that corresponds to this year. But, in each folder, data is not recorded in a single file, instead, in monthly files.

e.g. 1954 > APR, AUG, DEC... SEP

When I import these files using Glob and create a Dataframe with Pandas they're imported in this same order (above). But, instead, I need a correct months sequence (JAN, FEB, MAR..) for plotting and working with'em. So, my question is:

There is any way to force Glob importing files in a specific order or, maybe, rearrange files using Pandas?

```
    path = r'path'
    allFiles = glob.glob(path+"/*.dtf")

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    list_ = []
    for file_ in allFiles:
      df = pd.read_csv(file_,header = None,sep=r"\s*")
      list_.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(list_)
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you need one big `df` with all data? If use `df = pd.concat(list_, keys=allFiles)` what is `print (df.head())` ?

Comment: It create one big `df` with `MultiIndex` and first level should by path. So then next step is split path to years and months.

Comment: Not really, jezrael. But occasionally, If necessary, I'd,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` with filenames:

Data for testing are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u453ts7xy5kjn1l/AACvflpcOq_5hzmzt2L_rbSWa?dl=0).

```
path = r'path-dtfs'
#add /* for read subfolders
allFiles = glob.glob(path+"/*/*.dtf")
print (allFiles)
['path\\1954\\FEB.dtf', 'path\\1954\\JAN.dtf', 'path\\1955\\APR.dtf', 'path\\1955\\MAR.dtf']

list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,header = None,sep=r"\s+")
    list_.append(df)
```

Then create new columns by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html). For correct sorting need [ordered categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#object-creation)  with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.concat(list_, keys=allFiles)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .rename_axis('years').reset_index()

s = df['years'].str.split('\\')
df['years'] = s.str[-2].astype(int)
df.insert(1, 'months', s.str[-1].str.replace('.dtf', ''))

#add all missing months
cats = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR']
df['months'] = df['months'].astype('category', categories=cats, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values(['years','months']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   years months  0  1  2
0   1954    JAN  0  1  2
1   1954    JAN  1  5  8
2   1954    FEB  0  9  6
3   1954    FEB  1  6  4
4   1955    MAR  5  6  8
5   1955    MAR  4  7  9
6   1955    APR  0  3  6
7   1955    APR  1  4  1
```

Another solution is create `datetime` columns by [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.concat(list_, keys=allFiles)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .rename_axis('dates')
       .reset_index()
df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.extract('path\\\(.*).dtf', expand=False)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%Y\%b')
df = df.sort_values('dates').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       dates  0  1  2
0 1954-01-01  0  1  2
1 1954-01-01  1  5  8
2 1954-02-01  0  9  6
3 1954-02-01  1  6  4
4 1955-03-01  5  6  8
5 1955-03-01  4  7  9
6 1955-04-01  0  3  6
7 1955-04-01  1  4  1
```

Similar solution is use `month period` by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df = pd.concat(list_, keys=allFiles)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .rename_axis('periods').reset_index()
df['periods'] = df['periods'].str.extract('path\\\(.*).dtf', expand=False)
df['periods'] = pd.to_datetime(df['periods'], format='%Y\%b').dt.to_period('M')
df = df.sort_values('periods').reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
  periods  0  1  2
0 1954-01  0  1  2
1 1954-01  1  5  8
2 1954-02  0  9  6
3 1954-02  1  6  4
4 1955-03  5  6  8
5 1955-03  4  7  9
6 1955-04  0  3  6
7 1955-04  1  4  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to act as a `key` when sorting a list

suppose your list of files `allFiles` were (thanks @jezrael for the sample list):

```
allFiles = ['path/1954/FEB.dtf', 'path/1954/JAN.dtf',
            'path/1955/APR.dtf', 'path/1955/MAR.dtf']
```

Then define your key as

```
d = dict(JAN=0, FEB=1, MAR=2, APR=3)

def key(path):
    y, m = path.rsplit('.', 1)[0].split('/')[-2:]
    return int(y), d[m]
```

Use it in python's `sorted` function

```
sorted(allFiles, key=key)

['path/1954/JAN.dtf',
 'path/1954/FEB.dtf',
 'path/1955/MAR.dtf',
 'path/1955/APR.dtf']
```

Or you can alter the list in place with

```
allFiles.sort(key=key)
```

---

You can use it when importing:

```
pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(file_,header = None,sep=r"\s*")
     for file_ in sorted(allFiles, key=key)]
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, piRSquared!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` and the index of the months as `key` while getting the filenames in your code i.e

```
import os
path = r'path'
months = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JULY","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"]
allfiles= sorted(glob.glob(path+"/*.dtf"), key=lambda filename: [months.index(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0])])

df = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
  df = pd.read_csv(file_,header = None,sep=r"\s*")
  list_.append(df)
df = pd.concat(list_)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you a lot, Bharath Shetty!